# Windows service not able to delete a file

Tags: windows, file, file-upload, file-permissions

I've developed a service that generates a zip file and uploads it to my server (Tomcat) on the same network. However, one of our customers is encountering an issue where the file upload to the server fails.

When I run a PowerShell script to test connectivity, I found that a manually created file can be successfully uploaded to the server, but the file created by the service fails to upload.

Furthermore, I noticed that the manually created file can be uploaded to the server by the service, but it can't be deleted afterward.

The Windows service is currently running as the system user, and I've also tried running it as an admin user, but I'm still encountering the same error.

Could you please assist me in resolving this issue?

Comment: A common problem with ZIP files on Windows are anti-virus systems which try to scan the content and thus lock the file as it keeps an open file handle. As scanning a ZIP file can take some time, creating it manually may allow the anti-virus system to finish scanning before you try to delete the file. There are tools to check which process has open handles to a file, e.g. Sysinternals ProcessMonoitor or Sysinternals Handle (cmd-line).

Comment: @Robert, Thank you for your reply. I've tried disabling AV and Firewall also, but still facing the same issue. I'll try these tools to confirm the file is locked by any other process.

Any alternative suggestion would be welcomed.